# How to use It.IsAny<>(TValue) to match some properties of an object?

Tags: c#, moq

Consider following code. It has `BookingRequest` which contains two properties.  Interface `IBookingRequestProcessor` has a method to process `BookingRequest`. I want to create mocks which would match all `BookingRequest` object that match one property but other property can be any value.

For that I created mock matched object with matching properties set to values I want to match and other properties set to `It.IsAny<>()`. However, I get `Moq.MockException` with reason as `All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.`.

The complete code is as:

```
using System;
using Moq;

public class Program {

    public class BookingRequest
    {
        public string FlightId { get; set; }
        public string BookingId { get; set; }

        public BookingRequest() { }

        public BookingRequest(string FlightId, string BookingId)
        {
            this.FlightId = FlightId;
            this.BookingId = BookingId;
        }
    }

    public interface IBookingRequestProcessor
    {
        string ConstantReturn(string param);

        int ProcessBooking(BookingRequest bookingRequest);
    }
    
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        var bookingRequestMock = new Mock<IBookingRequestProcessor>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        bookingRequestMock
            .Setup(bp => bp.ConstantReturn(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns("AB");

        Console.WriteLine(bookingRequestMock.Object.ConstantReturn(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

        Console.WriteLine("----");

        var bookingRequestMatcher = new BookingRequest()
        {
            FlightId = "AB495",
            BookingId = It.IsAny<string>()
        };

        bookingRequestMock
            .Setup(bp => bp.ProcessBooking(bookingRequestMatcher))
            .Returns(495);

        var bookingRequest = new BookingRequest("AB495", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(bookingRequest.FlightId + " --> " + bookingRequestMock.Object.ProcessBooking(bookingRequest));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matching for mocked object properties have to be handled via `Is<TValue>()`. You can match based on required properties in following way:

```
bookingRequestMock
    .Setup(bp => bp.ProcessBooking(It.Is<BookingRequest>(br => br.FlightId == "AB495")))
    .Returns(495);
```